# Azure AD login page prompt

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I've a Azure AD registered web application built with ASP.Net Core and using OpenId Connect and cookies authentication and ADAL.
My web app only supports authentication against Work accounts.

I just noticed on the AAD login page that it says - "Work or school, or personal Microsoft account".

Can I indicate to AAD that the prompt should only say - "Work or school account".

Thanks, Donal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `msafed` parameter. Add the following to the query string:

```
msafed=0
```

Now users can only sign in with a "work or school account", i.e. an Azure AD account.